# Should Organization schema be on every page?

Tags: html, seo, schema, json-ld

I am trying to add schema to a product page.
The product is shackles used in lifting and rigging equipments.

However, in the footer of the page there is the address of the organization and also in the menu bar the links to all the other products is present.

I was wondering whether I should add organization schema to the product as the address and other products are present on the page.

The below is the schema

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@graph": [
        {
            "@type": "ProductGroup",
            "name": "Shackles",
            "description": "SVIBO industries is one of the top  D Shackles,bow Shackles manufacturers in India ",
            "aggregateRating": {
                "@type": "AggregateRating",
                "ratingValue": "4.9",
                "reviewCount": "18"
            },
            "url": "https://sviboindustries.in/shackles/",
            "hasVariant": [
                {
                    "@type": "Product",
                    "name": "Dee shackles",
                    "image": "https://sviboindustries.in/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/Dee-shackles.jpg",
                    "description": "D shackles, offer unmatched strength, versatility, and durability for a wide range of lifting, rigging, and fastening needs. Let’s explore why Dee Shackles are a preferred option for professionals worldwide.",
                    "aggregateRating": {
                        "@type": "AggregateRating",
                        "ratingValue": "4.9",
                        "reviewCount": "18"
                    },
                    "review": [
                        {
                            "@type": "Review",
                            "author": {
                                "@type": "Person",
                                "name": "Omkar Rawool"
                            },
                            "datePublished": "2021-05-18",
                            "reviewBody": "Don't Break",
                            "name": "Strong and reliable",
                            "reviewRating": {
                                "@type": "Rating",
                                "bestRating": "5",
                                "ratingValue": "4.9",
                                "worstRating": "1"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@type": "Review",
                            "author": {
                                "@type": "Person",
                                "name": "Prashant Sandwa"
                            },
                            "datePublished": "2022-01-01",
                            "reviewBody": "Good Quality Product from Svibo Industries.",
                            "name": "Good Service",
                            "reviewRating": {
                                "@type": "Rating",
                                "bestRating": "5",
                                "ratingValue": "4.9",
                                "worstRating": "1"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "@type": "Product",
                    "name": "Bow Shakles",
                    "image": "https://sviboindustries.in/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/Bow-Shackles.jpg",
                    "description": "Bow shackles, also known as anchor shackles, are essential components in lifting and rigging applications where secure connections and load distribution are paramount. ",
                    "aggregateRating": {
                        "@type": "AggregateRating",
                        "ratingValue": "4.9",
                        "reviewCount": "21"
                    },
                    "review": [
                        {
                            "@type": "Review",
                            "author": {
                                "@type": "Person",
                                "name": "Manthan Wadkar"
                            },
                            "datePublished": "2017-11-07",
                            "reviewBody": "Very Good",
                            "name": "This is a very good product",
                            "reviewRating": {
                                "@type": "Rating",
                                "bestRating": "5",
                                "ratingValue": "4.9",
                                "worstRating": "1"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@type": "Review",
                            "author": {
                                "@type": "Person",
                                "name": "Manthan Wadkar"
                            },
                            "datePublished": "2019-01-07",
                            "reviewBody": "Excellent",
                            "name": "Excellent",
                            "reviewRating": {
                                "@type": "Rating",
                                "bestRating": "5",
                                "ratingValue": "4.9",
                                "worstRating": "1"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "@type": "Organization",
            "name": "Svibo Industries",
            "url": "https://sviboindustries.in/",
            "logo": "https://sviboindustries.in/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/svibo-1.png",
            "image": "https://sviboindustries.in/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/svibo-1.png",
            "description": "Svibo Industries is broadly involved in manufacturing and supplying all types of Wire Ropes. Svibo provides all types of wire rope constructions of all grades.",
            "aggregateRating": {
                "@type": "AggregateRating",
                "ratingValue": "4.9",
                "reviewCount": "355"
            },
            "areaServed": {
                "@type": "State",
                "name": "MH"
            },
            "address": {
                "@type": "PostalAddress",
                "streetAddress": "111,112,113 Mahatma Phule Peth, Block No 101, Sevadham Building, 1st Floor, Pune, Maharashtra 411042",
                "addressLocality": "Pune",
                "addressRegion": "Maharashtra",
                "postalCode": "411042",
                "addressCountry": "IN"
            },
            "hasOfferCatalog": {
                "@type": "OfferCatalog",
                "name": "Products",
                "itemListElement": [
                    {
                        "@type": "Product",
                        "name": "Stainless Steel SS wire rope",
                        "aggregateRating": {
                            "@type": "AggregateRating",
                            "ratingValue": "4.9",
                            "reviewCount": "38"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "Product",
                        "name": "PVC Coated wire rope",
                        "aggregateRating": {
                            "@type": "AggregateRating",
                            "ratingValue": "4.9",
                            "reviewCount": "21"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "Product",
                        "name": "Galvanized wire rope",
                        "aggregateRating": {
                            "@type": "AggregateRating",
                            "ratingValue": "4.9",
                            "reviewCount": "10"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "Product",
                        "name": "Ungalvanized wire rope",
                        "aggregateRating": {
                            "@type": "AggregateRating",
                            "ratingValue": "4.9",
                            "reviewCount": "38"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "Product",
                        "name": "Polythene Slings",
                        "aggregateRating": {
                            "@type": "AggregateRating",
                            "ratingValue": "4.9",
                            "reviewCount": "40"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "Product",
                        "name": "Chain Sling and Alloy Chain",
                        "aggregateRating": {
                            "@type": "AggregateRating",
                            "ratingValue": "4.9",
                            "reviewCount": "40"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "Product",
                        "name": "Chain Pulley Block",
                        "aggregateRating": {
                            "@type": "AggregateRating",
                            "ratingValue": "4.9",
                            "reviewCount": "23"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "Product",
                        "name": "Lifting and Chain Hooks",
                        "aggregateRating": {
                            "@type": "AggregateRating",
                            "ratingValue": "4.9",
                            "reviewCount": "32"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "Product",
                        "name": "Electric Chain Hoist",
                        "aggregateRating": {
                            "@type": "AggregateRating",
                            "ratingValue": "4.9",
                            "reviewCount": "22"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "Product",
                        "name": "Eye Bolt",
                        "aggregateRating": {
                            "@type": "AggregateRating",
                            "ratingValue": "4.9",
                            "reviewCount": "15"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "Product",
                        "name": "Mini Electric Hoist",
                        "aggregateRating": {
                            "@type": "AggregateRating",
                            "ratingValue": "4.9",
                            "reviewCount": "32"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "Product",
                        "name": "Pulley, Pulleys Block and Chain Wheel",
                        "aggregateRating": {
                            "@type": "AggregateRating",
                            "ratingValue": "4.9",
                            "reviewCount": "56"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "Product",
                        "name": "Pulling and Lifting Machine",
                        "aggregateRating": {
                            "@type": "AggregateRating",
                            "ratingValue": "4.9",
                            "reviewCount": "21"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "Product",
                        "name": "Hand Puller",
                        "aggregateRating": {
                            "@type": "AggregateRating",
                            "ratingValue": "4.9",
                            "reviewCount": "10"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "Product",
                        "name": "Ratchet Lever Lifting Hoist",
                        "aggregateRating": {
                            "@type": "AggregateRating",
                            "ratingValue": "4.9",
                            "reviewCount": "32"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "Product",
                        "name": "Plate Lifting Clamps",
                        "aggregateRating": {
                            "@type": "AggregateRating",
                            "ratingValue": "4.9",
                            "reviewCount": "12"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "Product",
                        "name": "Trolley",
                        "aggregateRating": {
                            "@type": "AggregateRating",
                            "ratingValue": "4.9",
                            "reviewCount": "12"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "Product",
                        "name": "Winches",
                        "aggregateRating": {
                            "@type": "AggregateRating",
                            "ratingValue": "4.9",
                            "reviewCount": "32"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "Product",
                        "name": "Shackles",
                        "aggregateRating": {
                            "@type": "AggregateRating",
                            "ratingValue": "4.9",
                            "reviewCount": "40"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "Product",
                        "name": "Wire Rope Clamps",
                        "aggregateRating": {
                            "@type": "AggregateRating",
                            "ratingValue": "4.9",
                            "reviewCount": "31"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "Product",
                        "name": "Wire Rope Thimble",
                        "aggregateRating": {
                            "@type": "AggregateRating",
                            "ratingValue": "4.9",
                            "reviewCount": "42"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "Product",
                        "name": "Turnbuckle",
                        "aggregateRating": {
                            "@type": "AggregateRating",
                            "ratingValue": "4.9",
                            "reviewCount": "28"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "Product",
                        "name": "Safety Items",
                        "aggregateRating": {
                            "@type": "AggregateRating",
                            "ratingValue": "4.9",
                            "reviewCount": "15"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "contactPoints": [
                {
                    "@type": "ContactPoint",
                    "telephone": "+91 8208803755",
                    "contactType": "Customer support",
                    "email": "info@sviboindustries.com"
                },
                {
                    "@type": "ContactPoint",
                    "telephone": "+91 7447449114",
                    "contactType": "Customer support"
                },
                {
                    "@type": "ContactPoint",
                    "telephone": "+91 9637545481",
                    "contactType": "Customer support"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
</script>
```

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In this case the question has already been asked and answered there: [Should Schema.org Organization data about my company be on every page?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/82507/should-schema-org-organization-data-about-my-company-be-on-every-page)

Answer (score -2):

YES, Organization structured data is like a special tag we can add to our website to tell search engines more about our organization. It helps them understand who we are and what we do, which can make our website more visible to people searching online. So yeah, having Organization schema on every page is a good idea because it helps search engines connect better with our site.

Comment: Search engines have penalized sites for having org schema on every page.